# SQL insert into, where not exists (select 1... what this "1" stands for?

Tags: sql, insert, sql-server-2012

```
INSERT INTO table1 
SELECT * FROM table2 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 FROM table1 
    WHERE table2.id = table1.id)
```

What is the role of that `1` in the forth line of code? I want to make an incremental update of `table1` with records from `table2`. A friendly soul advised me to use the above query, which I find very common on the web in case of incremental update of a table. Can someone please explain how this mechanism works?

Comment: First it checks if the id is found in both tables. If it is TRUE then it returns 1. Then it checks if 1 not exists. Lets assume we have both tables the same. Then the 3rd line would be `WHERE NOT EXISTS 1`. How this line is processed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exists checks for the *presence* of rows in the sub-select, not for the data returned by those rows.

So we are only interested *if* there is a row or not.

But as you can't have a `select` without selecting something, you need to put an expression into the select list.

That could be *any* expression. The actual expression is of no interest You could use `select some_column` or `select *` or `select null` or `select 42` - that would all be the same.

Comment: Is it the speediest way for incremental update of a table? My suspicion arises from the fact that probably every row is checked. Since we have a unique sorted key maybe condition like `WHERE table2.id > MAX(table1.id)` would be faster?

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin: that is a totally different question. If you want to optimize that statement, please ask a **new** question.

Comment: Finally I got the logic. For anyone who wonders on that, it is like this. The subquery in brackets returns either '1' or 'NOT EXISTS'. If it does return 'NOT EXISTS' then it SELECT everything from table2. Thanks to everyone who contributed!

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin: it does not return `'NOT EXISTS'`, it returns _nothing_ (=no rows) if the value does not exist

Comment: Is `nothing` the same as `NULL`? Isn't it TRUE for the query NOT EXISTS?

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin: "no rows at all" is something different that one row containing a `null` value.

Answer (score 1):

You can select whatever in the case of `EXISTS (sub-select`, the only thing that matters are if a row is found (EXISTS true), or no rows found (EXISTS false).

Answer (score 1):

The `EXISTS` keyword, as the name suggests, is used to determine whether or not any rows exist in a table that meet the specified condition. Since we only need to filter out those rows which meet the condition, but do not need to actually retrieve the values of individual columns, we use `select 1` instead. For what it's worth, you can also write it as

```
INSERT INTO table1 
SELECT * FROM table2 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT id FROM table1 
WHERE table2.id = table1.id)
```

without affecting the filtering logic.